# Include files from different folder PHP

Tags: php

I know this question has been ask many times, but I couldn't find any proper answer which fix my issue.

My folder structure is:

```
 ├── index.php
 ├── js/
 │   └── js.js
 ├── css/
 │   └── style.css
 ├── src/
 │   └── include.php
 └── level1/
     └── index.php
```

In include.php:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In index.php:

```
<?php include('src/include.php');?> // works fine
```

In **level1/index.php**, I called

```
<?php include('../src/include.php');?> // js and css file included but points to level1 folder.
```

I want to keep the js & css style file inside js & css folder, respectively, and also still able to include them from different folders.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue?

Comment: add a slash before the `src`  `src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"` same goes for your style sheet

Comment: it points to main directory, not the application directory

Comment: then `src="/path/to/app/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"`

Comment: like @roullie said, you must set absolute URLs to the assets. Of course you must set the whole path like: `/path/to/my/public/assets/css/my-css.css`. Set this for js as well

Comment: src="`../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`" and `href="../css/style.css"`

Comment: @monace19 That won't work for the main `index.php` You don't want to use relative links at all in this situation.

Comment: oh right. my mistake

Comment: exactly, not working on index.php,

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: My url is "http://localhost/se/appname/" how I set the absolute url on include.php? keeping in view with folder structure I have

Comment: @Roger use an absolute link to your css/js. There's not much more we can do to help. If your app is at `http://example.com/myapp/index.php` for the main one, then then src should be `src="/myapp/js/` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You must understand the difference of "/" between php and css.For php,it start with your system's file-system,but for css/html/js,it means your webroot.

2.I use codes like this
On include.php

```
define("TEMPLATE_PATH",dirname(__FILE__)."/template");//this is for PHP file's include
include TEMPLATE_PATHE."/test.php";//php file as an example

define("WEB_TEMPLATE_PATH","/rain/template");//this is for html
<script src="<?=WEB_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?=WEB_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I wrote html and CSS together,does anyone can tell me if this is correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the `<script>` and `<link>` will use the directory relative to where they are included, meaning

```
js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

in one case, and

```
level1/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

To work around this problem, you can either prepend a `/` (as @roullie mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263150/include-files-from-different-folder-php/34263365#comment56267843_34263150)) if your directory structure is on root directory, or the full path like `/se/appname/`.

You can also provide some global instance returning the (absolute) base path to prevent typos and similar errors. For an example have a look at code igniters `base_url()` [here](http://Your%20problem%20is,%20that%20the%20%60%3Cscript%3E%60%20and%20%60%3Clink%3E%60%20will%20use%20the%20directory%20relative%20to%20where%20they%20are%20included,%20meaning).

Answer (score -1):

```
On include.php ,filepath will different for both locations

on index.php
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

because these file are including from index.php that is on root folder

On level1/index.php, I called
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
because these file are including from level1/index.php that is in level1 folder
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It adds unneeded redundancy. The include is there to eliminate that.

Comment: if you want to use common path then you have to use absolute path of that file