# Creating a universal header to be displayed on all pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've created a universal header that needs to be displayed across all pages of my website. This header contains images and links. The header's file name is *universal.php* and its CSS is *universal.css*.

These two files are located inside a folder called *test2*. The images of the header are located in a folder called *images* inside of *test2*.

So the pathway for the images in *test2* is: *images/example.png*. The links for the numerous pages of the header are located as files inside of *test2*, so the file paths for the links would be something like "*example.php*".

I created a new folder inside of *test2* called *article*. Inside of *article*, contains a file called *template.php*. I am trying to include the universal header inside of template, and this is what I have:

```
<?php
    require_once "../universal.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/test2/universal.css" /></head>
</html>
```

The header displays, but the pathways for the images and links are distorted. The images pathway's are now: test2/article/images/example.png (Which does not exist, so the images do not get displayed). Same thing for the links. The links are test2/article/example.php
The link and image pathway's are now relative to the template.php file. How do I make it so that the images and links are universally pinpointed to the right address?

Comment: change the url's of your links to an absolute path from the root.  and it should work.  see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263150/include-files-from-different-folder-php?noredirect=1#comment56267977_34263150)

Comment: @roullie what about the images?

Comment: same goes for your images path

Comment: @roullie So by absolute do you mean using the URL as so: http://www.example.com/test2/images/example.png ?

Comment: it doesn't need to  have a domain.  like for your example,  it should be /test2/images/example.png

Comment: @roullie Thanks a lot for your answer, it really helped!

Answer (score -1):

Look up absolute and relative paths.

What you want is to set all urls in `universal.php` to be absolute.